# Why is the other black power caller's name bleeped?

Tags: character, sorry-to-bother-you

In *Sorry to Bother You* (2018), whenever anyone is talking to the other black power caller (below),

[image]

his name is always censored. Looking in the [movie's IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5688932/characters/nm1165044?ref_=tt_cl_t4), the character is credited as "Mr.___" . Does anyone know the purpose or meaning of this? Any interviews with the writers where this is discussed?

Comment: It’s not explained in the movie. I though it might be that this character has a name, or nickname, that can not be articulated in “white voice”, and so must be bleeped by the powercallers, who must speak in white voice all the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

E! Online has a quote from [costume designer Deirdra Govan](https://www.eonline.com/news/952744/7-style-secrets-from-tessa-thompson-s-sorry-to-bother-you-you-probably-missed#photo-924955) :

> Mr. Blank's finalized look, which includes a bowler hat and eye patch,
>   was a combination of how Boots and Deirdra saw the character. Boots
>   wanted to use a leather shop in Oakland for the patch and Deirdra
>   pushed for the hat.
>
> "Mr. Blank was a really interesting character, in that **he has no
>   backstory**," the costume director shared. "**He's just a man that
>   appears.** For me, having studying art history and understanding
>   surrealism, the film itself is very surreal. I took that straight to
>   the place in Renee Magritte. **You have a man that has no clear name.
>   Even though we see his face, he's still a man without an identity.**"